# Scala: default return type of Option.getOrElse(...)

Tags: scala, types

The signature of the function `getOrElse(...)` of Scala's [`Option[+A]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) class is

```
 final def getOrElse[B >: A](default: ⇒ B): B
```

If I use the example

```
val o1 = Option("Hi")
val o2: Option[String] = Option(null)

println(o1.getOrElse(() => "Else"))
println(o2.getOrElse(() => "Else"))
```

I get the output

```
Hi
<function0>
```

The Scala API says about `getOrElse(...)`:

> Returns the option's value if the option is nonempty, otherwise return the result of evaluating `default`.

But `() => "Else")` is not evaluated.
The result cannot be evaluated by using brackets:

```
o2.getOrElse(() => "Else")()

error: Object does not take parameters
   o2.getOrElse( () => "Else")()
                              ^
```

How can I evaluate the result and why it is not evaluated automatically?

Is `default: ⇒ B` the same as `default: () ⇒ B` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *Is default: ⇒ B the same as default: () ⇒ B*

No, the first is call by name and the second is a thunk. The type of a call by name parameter is the type of the parameter itself, where the type of a thunk is `() => T` which is the same as `Function0[T]`.

When you do `o1.getOrElse(() => "Else")` you are working with heterogeneous types, so Scala will find the least common super type which is in this case is `Any`.

```
val orElse: Any = o1.getOrElse(() => "Else")
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```scala
val e: Function0[String] = () => "Else"
```

Then you can write:

```scala
println(o1.getOrElse(e)) //Hi
println(o2.getOrElse(e)) //<function0>
println(o2.getOrElse(e())) //Else
println(o2.getOrElse((() => "Else")())) //Else
```